# Is there a way to find out the column name of a Foreign key from a table using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Let's say I have two tables:

Client: ID(pk), Client Name

Order: ID(pk), Client_ID(fk), Order name

I want to find out the name of the foreign key column in the orders table.

I can get the name of primary key column using the following code:

```
     public static string prkFieldName<T>(this DataContext context) where T:class
    {
        var table = context.GetTable<T>();
        var mapping = context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(T));
        var prkfield = mapping.RowType.DataMembers.SingleOrDefault(d => d.IsPrimaryKey);
        if(prkfield==null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return prkfield.Name;
    }
```

But when I try to get the name of the foreign key column, i can only get to know that the 'CLient' table has been referenced. But I cannot know that the column name is 'Client_ID'.

In the end, I should be able to get the name of the column which is the foreign key. IS there any possibility? Thanks.

```
 public static string[] fkFieldName<T>(this DataContext context) where T : class
    {
        var table = context.GetTable<T>();
        var mapping = context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(T));

        var fkfield = mapping.RowType.DataMembers.Where(d => d.Association!=null).Where(s=>s.Association.IsForeignKey);


        if (fkfield == null)
        {
            return null;
        }


        var fkFieldNames = skfield.Select(c => c.Name).ToArray();

        return fkFieldNames;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to go back to the properties or field info and attributes, so the following works for me.

```
public static string[] fkFieldName<T>(this DataContext context ) where T : class
{
    var table = context.GetTable<T>();

    const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
    MemberInfo[] members = typeof(T).GetFields(bindingFlags).Cast<MemberInfo>()
                   .Concat(typeof(T).GetProperties(bindingFlags)).ToArray();

    var mapping = context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(T));

    var fkfield = mapping.RowType.DataMembers.Where(d => d.Association != null).Where(s => s.Association.IsForeignKey).ToList();

    string[] fkNames = new string[fkfield.Count()];

    for(int i= 0 ; i < fkfield.Count() ; i++)
    {
        var mi = members.Single(a=>a.Name == fkfield[i].Name) ;
        var attr = (System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute)mi.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute));
        fkNames[i] = attr.ThisKey;
    }
    return fkNames;
}
```